# $X$ and $Y$ are ordered set, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology, self-learning, connectedness, order-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ are ordered set in the order topology. Show that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

**My attempt:**

Simply $f$ is bijective (take $x<y\Longleftrightarrow f(x)<f(y)$ to reduce cases.). Easy to see that $f([a,b])=[f(a),f(b)]$. Let $A$ be a connected subset of $Y$. Then $\color{red}{\bar A=[\inf A,\sup A]}$. So $f^{-1}(\bar A)$ is closed set. Again if $B,C$ are two disjoint connected open sets, then $f^{-1}(B\cup C)=f^{-1}(B)\cup f^{-1}(C)$.

Is my proof ok.(Mainly the red part?)

Comment: Can someone please check if my argument is correct or not.

Comment: Why does this show that $f$ is a homeomorphism (so its inverse is continuous ?)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It is given that $x<y\Longleftrightarrow f(x)<f(y)$, so two ways to go: for $f^{-1}$, $x<y\Rightarrow f(x)<f(y)$ and for $f$, $x<y\Leftarrow f(x)<f(y)$. Am I wrong?

Comment: If for $f$ we have $x_1 < x_2 \leftrightarrow f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ and $f$ is surjective, then $f$ is bijective and thus has an inverse $g: Y \to X$ which also obeys $y_1 < y_2 \leftrightarrow g(y_1) < g(y_2)$, as can easily be checked.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thanks, but as for fact is my argument of showing $f$ is continuous ok? I am self-studying topology, and this is a problem in the section about connectedness. So I want to use that. So I want to know if my argument is ok or not. Otherwise I have to live with **punctured concept**.

Comment: Your argument doesn't show homeomorphism.

Comment: It doesn't show $f$ is continuous. For that we need to show that the inverse image of open sets is open. And the inverse of a continuous bijection is not always continuous.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But $f^{-1}(\text{closed set})=\text{closed set}\Rightarrow$ continuity on $f$, isn't.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma bijection do not imply continuity. But here $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are similar type of function.

Comment: But you don't start with an arbitrary closed set, but only consider closures of connected sets.

Comment: Let $A,B$ are open connected disjoint sets, $\overline{A\cup B}$ is either connected or differs by a open set between them. @HennoBrandsma I used this argument at the end, is this ok?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you need connectedness at all. 
Check that $f$ is continuous and its inverse $g$ as well.
$f$ continuous is clear as $f^{-1}[(a,\rightarrow)] = (g(a), \rightarrow)$ as $f$ is strictly increasing. Similarly for the other subbasic elements $(\leftarrow, a)$: $f^{-1}[(\leftarrow,a)] = (\leftarrow, g(a))$.
As $f$ is a strictly increasing function, so is $g$, and the same argument applies to show $g$ is continuous.