# Show that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ are ordered set in the order topology. Show that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

i got the answer  here [$X$ and $Y$ are ordered set, $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is order preserving and surjective, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415282/x-and-y-are-ordered-set-fx-rightarrow-y-is-order-preserving-and-surjecti)  ..  but i didn't understand   it[image]

Comment: $(a,\rightarrow) = \{x \mid a < x\}$

Comment: If you are not familiar with notations used by someone answering your question then just ask about in a comment on the answer. Also if you don't understand the answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher that mean  ($\leftarrow$,a)  = ${x|a>x}$  ,....Am i right ??

Comment: Yes. You are right. It saves from having to  separately list the cases where $X$ or $Y$ does or does not have a max or min member

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ordered space $X$, with linear order $<$, the topology is generated by two types of sets:$(\leftarrow,p)=\{x \in X: x < p\}$, where $p\in X$ can be any point, and all sets of the form $(p,\rightarrow)=\{ x \in X: x > p\}$, again with $p \in X$. Such sets are all open by definition in the order topology, and they form a subbase for it.

In the linked answer the useful fact is used that a function is continuous iff the inverse images of subbasic elements are open.

Comment: thanks   a  lots @Henno sir

Comment: @lomber better to ask as a comment to the original question though.

Comment: i was thinking,,,,that there  will be  no response   if  i coomment on  orginal question post,,,,so i decided  that   upload the  new  post..@henno sir

Comment: @lomber the answerer gets notifications for new comments.